# Cannot connect to the new user created on Oracle database 18 XE in Docker

Tags: oracle, docker, oracle-xe, oracle18c

I recently built an image of oracle database 18xe using [this script](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images) and created a container with following command:

```
$docker run --name myxedb \
-d \
-p 51521:1521 \
-p 55500:5500 \
-e ORACLE_PWD=hr \
-e ORACLE_CHARACTERSET=AL32UTF8 \
oracle/database:18.4.0-xe
```

Right after that I logged in with following command:

```
$docker exec -it --user=oracle myxedb bash
$. oraenv
>XE
$sqlplus sys@XEPDB1 as sysdba
```

Then I created an user on the oracle database using the following query:

```
ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER = XEPDB1;
CREATE USER hra IDENTIFIED BY hr;
GRANT CONNECT TO hra;
```

But when I go to sqldeveloper and try to connect the hra user, I get this 
[**error**,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKRka.jpg) though I  can log in as [**sys**.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ANZE.jpg)

P.S:I am using OpenSuse 15.1 leap and docker 19.03.5.

Comment: Can you post the images inline.  Even better if the stack trace is posted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created your user in the pluggable database (SERVICE_NAME=XEPDB1), but you are logging in to the container database (SID=XE). SYS exists in both. Change the service name in your SQL Developer connection.

Comment: Also, You created user HR, but then granted privs to user HRA.  HR != HRA..  Is that a typo because you transcribed what you thought you did, vs. actually copying and pasting your session to show us what you _really_ did?

Comment: Thanks for you response, I am sorry i did that mistake while taking the screenshot although it had the same result with user hra. Also I got this error => https://imgur.com/lSl9yjp when i changed the service name to XEPDB1

Comment: That should be the service_name, not the SID.